# How to make simple image to animated image like GIF?

Tags: android, image-editing

I wont to make simple image to Animated image like GIF.I can select the image for gallery and store in image file.But, How i can modify image file to animated image or GIF File .

Comment: use gif Encoder to merge images and create animation

Comment: but how it possible?

Comment: can you give me a any  code in ans?

Answer (score 3):

you have to select images you want to make GIF, then use bitmaps and run code in background Thread/Asynchtask:

Here i used Drawable, in your case convert images into bitmap and use it.

```
            Bitmap one=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.neon0);
            Bitmap two=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.neon1);
            Bitmap three=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.neon2);


            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            AnimatedGifEncoder encoder = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
            encoder.start(bos);


            encoder.addFrame(one);
            encoder.addFrame(two);
            encoder.addFrame(three);
            encoder.finish();

            FileOutputStream outStream;
            try{
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + 
                "/IMAGES_GIF/" + "animated.gif");
                outStream.write(bos.toByteArray());
                outStream.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Get Class from:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wasabeef/8785346/raw/53a15d99062a382690275ef5666174139b32edb5/AnimatedGifEncoder.java

Comment: thanks. ,but i want only  one image  to  convert  in Gif like animation not using multiple images. can you give me a some guiedence for the wave animation

Comment: means you want to animate single image parts?

Comment: i want only  1 image to convert GIf and set in animation.it possible?

Comment: you can not create animation from single image.For that you need to use Some software to animate part from single image merge that parts in GIF file.

Comment: can i  set a single image on wave animation?

Comment: means wave animation and above it single image with transparency?

Comment: give direct animation  on image like wave. or set make gif like wave animation  using single image.

Comment: http://www.netanimations.net/Water-waterfalls-lake-stream-ocean-animated-gifs.htm

Comment: i have no idea how to create that animation using single image. above link shows gifs that uses multiple images

Answer (score 1):

This question needs a lot more information. Is the file already a GIF and it is not animating or are you trying to convert an image to a GIF? The latter is not possible, a GIF is a series of images.

You must create the GIF elsewhere and it is easiest to use a library like Glide (https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or Picasso (http://square.github.io/picasso/) to load the GIF.

Comment: your mins i can crate multiple image and modify  in GIF?