# How to convert a bitmap image to a gif in xamarin android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to convert an bitmap image to gif format in xamarin android. can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can animate multiple images, you can not create animation from single image.

For multiple images, you want to make gif, you can take a look the following thread:
[How to make simple image to animated image like GIF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757632/how-to-make-simple-image-to-animated-image-like-gif)

Comment: not an animated gif just a gif based format with one single frame/image

Comment: I think it is impossible to create animation from single image.

Comment: ok. assume I have several bitmap images. how to convert them to gif? note that the System.Drawing namespace can not be used in xamarin android.